# Does the wording ' lifted up from the earth' have a deeper meaning?

Tags: john, jesus

We hear Jesus saying in Jn 12:32-33. (KJV):

> 32.And I, if I be lifted up from the earth, will draw all men unto me.33. This he said, signifying what death he should die.

If Verse 32 is read in isolation, it could be interpreted as a prophecy on Jesus' crucifixion or  the resurrection or  the ascension. The wording somehow gives a hint to detachment from the earth . Jesus was still 'attached' to the earth on his death and burial. After the Resurrection,  he forbids Mary to touch him saying that he has not yet ascended to the Father (Jn 20:17). That again, hints that he was attached to the earth till at the time of ascension. But, Verse 33 from the side of the Evangelist leaves no scope for speculation. Be that as it may, the wording of 'lifted up from the earth' is found across all versions. Does it actually have a deeper meaning ?

Comment: I agree with you that scripture always has a deeper meaning hidden beneath the words.  Jesus knew the way in which he was going to die by crucifixion.  On the other hand, he knew death 
would not hold Him  down, because His Father was going to lift him up out of death and out of earths realm.  Because of this all  men would be dragged to Himself.

Answer (score 5):

At least three times Jesus made a statement about being "lifted up" -

- John 3:13, 14 - Just as Moses **lifted up** the snake in the wilderness, so the Son of Man must be **lifted up**, that everyone who believes in Him may have **eternal life**.
- John 8:28 - So Jesus said, “When you have **lifted up** the Son of Man, then you will know that **I am**, and that I do nothing on My own, but speak exactly what the Father has taught Me.
- John 12:32 - And I, when I am **lifted up** from the earth, will **draw everyone to Myself**.”

Allow me to offer several comments about these statements:

1. Note the three distinct but closely related outcomes of Jesus being exalted: eternal life, a recognition that Jesus is the "I Am", and drawing all people to Himself (not all will accept).
2. The three statements clearly refer in the first instance to Jesus being "lifted up" on the cross
3. However, there is almost certainly a secondary application of these lifted up/exalted statements of Jesus as recorded by Paul using a very similar cognate verb:

> Phil 2:8-11 - And being found in appearance as a man, He humbled
> Himself and became obedient to death— even death on a cross.
>
> Therefore God **exalted** Him to the highest place and gave Him the
> name **above** all names, that at the name of Jesus every knee should
> bow, in heaven and on earth and under the earth, and every tongue
> confess that Jesus Christ is Lord, to the glory of God the Father.

This statement is a direct quote from Isa 45:23.

Thus, Jesus' statements about being lifted up appear to point back to the prophecy of Isaiah and forward to both the crucifixion as well as Jesus exaltation after resurrection and ascension.

Comment: Thanks, Dottard, for the resourceful inputs. The focus of my question is "... from the earth". Sorry if I have confused you. Last para of your answer is closer to the point.

Answer (score 2):

The question seems to be based on the idea that *"If Verse 32 is read in isolation it could be interpreted as..."*. Actually, the words quoted are only half of a sentence that began in verse 31. The conjunction "and" at the start of verse 32 indicates this. It is therefore necessary to quote the full sentence Jesus spoke if the depth of the interpretation sought be discovered.

> "Now is the judgment of this world: now shall the prince of this world
> be cast out, and I, if I be lifted up from the earth, will draw all
> unto me." John 12:31-32 KJV

Please note that the Greek text of the KJV does not have the word for *'men'* in it. Jesus said what John records. By his being crucified, he "would draw all unto him" - those whom the Father gave to him. "No man can come to me, except the Father which hath sent me draw him" - John 6:44. The question being asked here, however, dwells on how to interpret the meaning of "lifted up from the earth".

**This is where the word "hour" comes in**, stated by Jesus in verses 23 and 27:

> "The hour is come, that the Son of man should be glorified."
>
> "What shall I say? Father save me from this hour; but for this cause
> came I unto this hour."

The "hour" involved was not a 60-minute hour. It signified a relatively short span of time (when compared to other biblical phrases involving length of time, such as 1,260 days, 'a little season', and three and a half times as in several prophecies; yet longer than the silence in heaven for about half an hour, Rev.8:1.)

Jesus spoke of his hour *not* yet having come prior to him changing water into wine at Cana. Then he said his hour *had* come when going to Jerusalem for the last time. When did that symbolic hour start and end? John informs us:

> "Now before the feast of the passover, when Jesus knew that his hour
> was come that he should depart out of this world unto the Father,
> having loved his own which were in the world, he loved them unto the
> end." John 13:1 KJV

It follows, then, that **everything that happened from the time (just before the feast of the passover) until he departed the world to return to the Father gives the full meaning to being "lifted up from the earth".** ***It incorporates both the cross he was nailed to being literally lifted upright for all who passed by to see, and his being resurrected, seen by hundreds of his disciples, finally rising bodily up into the sky,*** till clouds hid him from their sight (Acts 1:9-11).

Picking up again from verse 33, this commentary highlights ***the significance of 'this hour' (which is crucial to get the full depth of meaning sought***.)

> "The Son had glorified the Father, by the works which the Father had
> given him to do, and by the words which he had given him to speak.
> Till 'now'. But now in and through the Son the Father would glorify
> his name again, and that in a manner without precedent, and in a way
> that would be unique.
>
> Unique, that is, to 'this hour', this coming hour, even as Jesus had
> said 'For this cause' - so as to glorify the Father - 'came I unto
> this hour.' This was the 'hour' which commenced at the approaching
> crucifixion, resurrection and ascension of the Son. 'This he said,
> signifying what death he should die', John 12:33.
>
> Thus the Father would be glorified again. How? By his *then* and
> *there* judging the world, and hence casting out the prince of this world in consequence, John 12:31.
>
> Judging the world? But of that we read at the last judgment at the end
> of the age in the terrible conflagration, II Peter 3:7-12. That is
> true of the Day of Judgment. But it is *also* true of the *transferred
> equivalent of that same judgment* which was *then* to fall upon Jesus
> at Golgotha. Hence, '*now* is the judgment of this world', John 12:21.
>
> Then, Jesus is speaking of *the judgment of the world falling upon the
> crucified Saviour*... To this end 'he was made sin for us, who knew no
> sin', II Corinthians 5:21. It is a question of sin, not sins. As to
> sin, it is common to all mankind, to the world. Whereas sins are
> individual. But to save sinners - apart from bearing *their* sins -
> the sin of mankind, of humanity, of the world, must *also* be
> judged...
>
> Every issue of the judgment of the sin of man fell upon the Saviour:
> 'Now is the judgment of this world.' This saved the world from its
> immediate deserved destruction and dissolution. This caused God to
> suffer time to run on, till the judgment that was transferred, and
> thus deferred, should be consummated at the end of the world.
>
> But if the sin of the world was judged, it must follow, the prince of
> this world was dispossessed. That on which he relied, his whole armour
> wherein he trusted, the very gates and walls of his citadel, the power
> of his kingdom, were utterly taken from him.
>
> If so, *he* fell. As it is written, 'Now shall the prince of this
> world be cast out', John 12:31. Whence it is obvious that when Jesus
> was 'made sin' in that 'hour', and 'took away the sin of the world',
> then all that gave the prince of this world his legitimate power and
> authority *was lawfully answered and legally dismissed.* 'And I, if I
> be lifted up from the earth, will draw all to myself. But this he
> said, signifying by what death he was about to die, John 12:32,33."
> *John chapters 1 to 12 - The first six signs*, John Metcalfe, 2006,
> pp.479-480, http://johnmetcalfepublishingtrust.co.uk/contact_us.htm

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the word in the Greek first to see what's its meaning is.

- **Strong's Concordance, hupsoó:** to lift or raise up, to exalt, uplift

  **Original Word:** ὑψόω

  **Part of Speech:** Verb

  **Transliteration:** hupsoó

  **Phonetic Spelling:** (hoop-so'-o)

  **Definition:** to lift or raise up, to
  exalt, uplift

  **Usage:** (a) I raise on high, lift up, (b) I exalt, set
  on high.

[Ellicott's Commentary for English Readers](https://biblehub.com/commentaries/ellicott/john/12.htm)

> Note on John 14:3. The words “lifted up” have occurred before in John
> 3:14; John 8:28; but the context here shows that they **include the
> thought of the ascension into heaven.** It is from the heavenly throne
> that the Messiah will rule over His spiritual kingdom.

[MacLaren Expositions Of Holy Scripture](https://biblehub.com/commentaries/maclaren/john/12.htm)

> But now there is another point suggested by these remarkable words,
> and that is that **our Lord regarded the Cross of shame as exaltation or
> ‘lifting up.’** I do not believe that the use of this remarkable phrase
> in our text finds its explanation in the few inches of elevation above
> the surface of the ground to which the crucified victims were usually
> raised. That is there, of course, but there is something far deeper
> and more wonderful than that in the background, and it is this in
> part, that that Cross, to Christ’s eyes, bore a double aspect.

These are what I believe are the three possible interpretations:

- **Exaltation:** The term could refer to Jesus' exaltation and glorification, shown by his resurrection and ascension
  post-crucifixion, marking his triumph over sin, death, and dark
  forces, as illustrated in Philippians 2:9-11.
- **Crucifixion:**  "lifted up" could refer to Jesus' crucifixion on the cross. This act of being lifted up from the earth symbolizes Jesus'
  sacrificial death for the salvation of humanity. Through his
  crucifixion, Jesus would bear the sins of the world and provide
  redemption for all who believe in him (John 3:14-15).
- **Accension:** The ascension is recorded in several passages of the New Testament, including Luke 24:50-53, Acts 1:9-11, and Mark 16:19.
  These accounts describe how Jesus, after spending 40 days with his
  disciples following his resurrection, ascended into heaven from the
  Mount of Olives in Jerusalem. This verse could be referring to when
  he would go and sit at the right hand of the Father. (Psalm 110:1)

Answer (score 1):

Does the wording ' lifted up from the earth' have a deeper meaning?

The answer is in the next verse. John 12:33 which says "But this he said, signifying by what manner of death he should die". It refers to Jesus' execution on a stake. The immediate context provides the answer to the question. John 12:32 should not be read in isolation.

There is nothing to support the idea that it means "a recognition that Jesus is the "I Am" and drawing all people to Himself" Jesus was not the God that spoke to Moses as Mark 12:26-27 and Acts 3:13 show.

Mark 12:26-27 ASV

But as touching the dead, that they are raised; have ye not read in the book of Moses, in the place concerning the Bush, how **God** spake unto him, saying, I am the God of Abraham, and the God of Isaac, and the God of Jacob? He is not the God of the dead, but of the living: ye do greatly err.

If Jesus was the God that spoke to Moses, Jesus could have said, "But as touching the dead, that they are raised; have ye not read in the book of Moses, in the place concerning the Bush, how **I** spoke to him saying, I am the God of Abraham, and the God of Isaac, and the God of Jacob? He is not the God of the dead, but of the living: ye do greatly err"

Acts 3:13 ASV

The God of Abraham, and of Isaac, and of Jacob, the God of our fathers, hath glorified his Servant Jesus; whom ye delivered up, and denied before the face of Pilate, when he had determined to release him.

Just as during the time of Moses and the Israelites in the wilderness  the serpent made of copper was raised on a pole for Israelites to gaze if bitten by snake in order to live, Jesus was the man provided by God for others to live. I Corinthians 15:21.

1 Corinthians 15:21 ASV

For since by man came death, by man came also the resurrection of the dead.